# get day month and year from this format using javascript

Tags: javascript, date, twitter

i am facing issue while manipulating data from this format

```
Fri Dec 23 2011 18:37:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

i am getting this format from twitter and need to display only day and month as per my requirement. Can any one help me to get specifications from this format. or can we have different format from twitter as well.

share your views.

Comment: read : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Split](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html#split) in javascript, to split the datetime after converting in to a string.  Use the first two parts for your purpose.

```
var b = 'I am a JavaScript hacker.'
var temp = new Array();
temp = b.split(' ');
```

Now the string has been split into 5 strings that are placed in the array temp. The spaces themselves are gone.

```
temp[0] = 'I';
temp[1] = 'am';
temp[2] = 'a';
temp[3] = 'JavaScript';
temp[4] = 'hacker.';
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response. it works in firefox n chrome. but not on IE here  is my requirement:  


    var d = new Date("Thu Dec 22 13:36:36 +0000 2011");

 it is not working on IE and thanks for sharing jsFiddle.net link it help and will help me in near future. Please share your view for above to work on ie as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct `Date` object with the provided string and retrieve the details as follows:

HTML

```
 <div id="timeDiv"></div>​
```

JavaScript

```
 var d = new Date("Fri Dec 23 2011 18:37:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)");
 var weekday=["Sun","Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
 var month = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];

 $("#timeDiv").text('Month : ' + month[d.getMonth()] 
                    + ' and Day : ' + weekday[d.getDay()]);​​​
```

[Demo on jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/3K6du/2/)

For more information on `Date` object check [w3School](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Hope this helps  you.

Comment: have u checked your fiddle?? it display `23-12-111`

Comment: thanks for your quick response. it works in firefox n chrome. but not on IE here  is my requirement:

Comment: it should work for ie8 n 9.. i am trying on jdfiddle.net and getting NaN undefined

Comment: here is the code:

 function formatDutchDate() {
    var d = new Date("Thu Dec 22 13:36:36 +0000 2011");
    monthnames = ['januari','februari','maart','april','mei','juni','juli','augustus','september','oktober','november','december'];
    monthname = monthnames[d.getMonth()];
      
    $("#timeDiv").text (d.getDate() +' '+monthname);
}

formatDutchDate();

Comment: var d = new Date("Fri Dec 23 13:07:45 +0000 2011"); 

  console.log(d); //invalid date in ie

Comment: Right... the date format you have given can not be parsed by IE. `Thu Dec 22 2011 13:36:36 +0000` date can be parsed. From where you are getting these date formats? Also how many formats you need to handle?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <html>
  <body>

   <script type="text/javascript">

    var d = new Date("Fri Dec 23 2011 18:37:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)");
    alert(d.getDate() + '/' + d.getMonth());

   </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: share your view for this format var d = new Date("Thu Dec 22 13:36:36 +0000 2011");

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps to solve your problem:

1. Create `Date` object with this information;
2. Retrieve year and month from this object.

## Step 1

Create the `Date` object with the information from the string.

```
var dateinfo = new Date("Fri Dec 23 2011 18:37:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)");
```

## Step 2

Retrieve the day and month info from the new dateinfo object.

```
// Retrieve the day 
dateinfo.getDay();
// Retrieve the month
// Attention here, the month is indexed under 0
dateinfo.getMonth();
```

You could retrieve more information from [the MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: share your view for var d = new Date("Thu Dec 22 13:36:36 +0000 2011");  as well

Comment: more concise declaration :) Edited.